# how to reset soft keyboard with libgdx to make it in normal state?

Tags: android, keyboard, libgdx, android-softkeyboard

I encountered an issue yesterday, and now I still don't know how to resolve it.
The question only appears in Samsung device.
When I invoke the libgdx's soft keyboard after leaving dial screen, the soft keyboard will
be changed to "numberSigned" type automatically. My question is why so? And how can I do to 
turn it to normal type?